# Usando Voter com Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, acl, symfony4

estou aprendendo *Symfony 4* e estou me deparando com um problema. Na versão 4 do *Symfony* o *ACL* foi descontinuado e pelo que vi estão usando o *Voter*. Já pesquisei na internet e na documentação mas estou perdido, não estou conseguindo entender. Alguém que usa o *Voter* para implementação de *ACL* com *Symfony 4* pode me auxiliar com um tutorial mais completo?
Valeu

Answer (score 0):

Não sei quanto a versões anteriores ao Symfony 3 mas o Symfony sempre utilizou voters, por isso qualquer tutorial sobre voters para uma versão mais antiga do Symfony também da para a versão 4.

https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security/voters.html